# Combinatoric: Find words of length 4 where A,B,C occurs at least once

Tags: combinatorics

Let $\Sigma = \{{A,B,C}\}$ be our alphabet. Find all words of the length 4 in which every letter occurs at least once e.g. AABC, ABBC, CBBA, CABA, ..

I know that the answer is:
$3 \binom42 2= 36$

but unfortunately I don't understand *why* this is the case.

Could anybody explain this to me?

Please excuse this rather simple question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One letter must be doubled.  There are three choices (A,B or C).

Those double letters occupy two places out of four.  There are ${4\choose 2}$ ways to do that.

Lastly, there are two slots for the other two letters.  There are two ways to fill them.

Comment: Oh I got it now.. how could I not see that? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it:

There are in total $3^4$ possible words without any restriction.

Let's count the number of words that do not verify the condition given:

- The number of words which do not contain the letter $A$ is $2^4$
- The number of words which do not contain the letter $B$ is $2^4$
- The number of words which do not contain the letter $C$ is $2^4$

Since the words $AAAA$, $BBBB$, $CCCC$ are in two of the previous cases, if we just sum the numbers, we are counting them twice. Hence, the number of words in which a certain letter does not appear is $3 \cdot 2^4-3=45$

Therefore, the number of words in which every letter appears at least once is $81-45=36$